# ASP.NET MVC 3 - DBContext Class Not Being Executed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-5

I am trying to seed my application with some test data via EF Code First, when the app starts up.

**Here is what I am observing:**

When I run the app, execution goes into:

```
Application_Start() {}
```

And then once in Application_Start() it lands on:

```
Database.SetInitializer<LocatorContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<LocatorContext>());
```

But it never makes it into the DBContext class (ClubLocatorContext.cs),
which is where the seeding happens, among other things.

Any thoughts as to why or how I can fix it would be much appreciated.

**My Global.asax.cs File**

```
//Global.asax.cs
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<LocatorContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<LocatorContext>());

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

**My DBContext Class**

```
//ClubLocatorContext.cs        
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using ClubLocator.Models;
using ClubLocator.Models.ViewModels;

namespace ClubLocator.DAL
{
    public class LocatorContext : DbContext
    {

      public DbSet<Prospect> Prospects { get; set; }

      protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
          base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
          modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
      }

      public void Seed(LocatorContext context)
      {
          var prospect = new List<Prospect>
                         {
                              new Prospect
                              {
                                      FirstName = "John",
                                      LastName = "Smith",
                                      Address1 = "1313 Mockingbird Lane",
                                      Email = "jsmith@example.com"
                              }
                         };

          prospect.ForEach(r => context.Prospects.Add(r));
          context.SaveChanges();
      }

      public class DropCreateIfChangeInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<LocatorContext>
      {
          protected override void Seed(LocatorContext context)
          {
              context.Seed(context);
              base.Seed(context);
          }
      }

      public class CreateInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<LocatorContext>
      {
          protected override void Seed(LocatorContext context)
          {
              context.Seed(context);
              base.Seed(context);
          }
      }

      static LocatorContext()
      { 
          #if DEBUG
          Database.SetInitializer<LocatorContext> (new DropCreateIfChangeInitializer ());
          #else
          Database.SetInitializer<LocatorContext> (new CreateInitializer ());
          #endif
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just setting initializer, not initialized. When you access the database it will create the database and seed data.

Comment: Jason, Thanks. What would that look like from inside Application_Start():?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new DropCreateIfChangeInitializer()
                .InitializeDatabase(new LocatorContext());
```

Comment: Jason, I see that method in my context class but intellisense in VS doesn't like that syntax. Can you show me what it should look like from inside Application_Start()? Thanks

Comment: You created DropCreateIfChangeInitializer which extends DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<LocatorContext> which has public method InitializeDatabase. So I don't understand why you can't invoke the method in Application_Start

Comment: It's weird. The only 2 methods that come up in intellisense are DropCreateDatabaseAlways<> and DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<>

Comment: protected void Application_Start()
{
    new DropCreateIfChangeInitializer()
                .InitializeDatabase(new LocatorContext());}

Comment: If still not work, you can paste your code in application_start.

Comment: I got your suggestion to compile by prefixing with new LocatorContext.DropCreate... But it still doesn't seed the data. It goes into OnModelCreating() method in my context class and that's it